# Can Minecraft spiders turn corners while climbing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I have a tall square tower, and a spider is climbing up one side of it, can it continue around to another side while still climbing? Or would it have to start climbing from the bottom again?

Similarly, if it were inside the tower and climbing on the inner wall, can it turn an inside corner and keep going? (I'm assuming yes on this one, seems easier.)

Comment: Can you turn corners while climbing a ladder? The climbing behavior mimics ladders, as far as I know.

Comment: Does the video not answer your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Spiders cannot turn corners on the inside or the outside of a structure.  They can move along a wall, but fall off when they try to cross a vertical corner.  This video isn't a perfect demonstration but it does show in a couple of parts how the spider gets stuck trying to go round a corner. [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GC8959uvEE0)

Comment: Do you have any references?  Links?  Screenshots?  The relevant bit of code?

Comment: i tested this ingame...but i will add a vid of someone testing how spider climb walls

Comment: This is your friendly reminder that I am still waiting on that vid.   :)

Comment: :| click the link on here up there ^^ takes you to the vid :D

Comment: Ah sorry missed that. Very good. Have an upvote.  :)

Comment: The linked video doesn't answer whether or not a spider can turn an interior corner, it only demonstrates that they can't turn an exterior corner.

Comment: Good video, but doesn't answer the question. Someone needs to build a tower (or wall), attract spiders to it, and see how they behave.

Comment: i would but i have issues recording minecraft, my computer is a bit slow.

Comment: Its a bit late now but seeing as this post is not yet closed i will try this in a few hours when im home.